# Appending a sequence file in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a live streaming tweets which I need to store in HDFS . Currently I can access the live tweets and able to extract the information from those tweets . My requirement is such that I need to append all the tweets into a single sequence file in HDFS . However I have thought to resolve this issue by two ways . Either I can make a single tweet to store into a small file in HDFS and periodically I can bundle them into a single sequence file .The second approach which i thought of is at the run time I would read the sequence file and then append the new contents into the sequence file .

Please let me know which approach I should go for . Kindly also suggest me if there is any better solution for handling these type of use cases .

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Flume. 
You can see how Tweets are streamed into HDFS in this example:
https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example